# Embed a ViewController to a UIContainerView from different Storyboards

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue, uicontainerview

Is there a way to embed a view controller from one storyboard into a UIContainerView from a different storyboard?

I want to take advantage of the UIContainerView, but without using the storyboard based embed segue. I don't know if it's possible..

Comment: See the example code in [Implementing a Custom Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12) in Apple's view controller programming guide.